# Manipulating list after function performs recursion

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to perform some recursive function on a list, and after the recursion is done, I would like to access the output list from the recursion to perform an additional operation.

For example, the function below, takes in a value to keep and a list, and it returns a list with only the values to keep, throwing away all the others.

What I would like to do, is understand how I can get access to output list after the recursion took place, so I can continue to operate on it.

Something like:

```
//recursive function here

//get length of output list from recursive function
length list
```

My Function

```
keepAll _ [] = []
keepAll y (x:xs) | x==y = y:keepAll y xs
                 | otherwise = keepAll y xs
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from function composition for the general case, you can also assign a specific result of keepAll to a variable and work with that value later:

```
outputList = keepAll 3 [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,3]
print (init outputList)   >> [3,3,3]
print (length outputList) >> 4
```

If you would like to access the output list of the recursion inside your function, you might want to delegate the recursion to a "helper" function inside, for example:

```
keepSome y (x:xs) = keepAll y (x:xs)
  where keepAll _ [] = []
        keepAll y (x:xs) | x==y = y:keepAll y xs
                         | otherwise = keepAll y xs
```

Now you can change the first line so it applies "init" to the result of the recursion, as you suggested:

```
keepSome y (x:xs) = init $ keepAll y (x:xs)
  where keepAll _ [] = []
        keepAll y (x:xs) | x==y = y:keepAll y xs
                         | otherwise = keepAll y xs
```

You could also, for example, name the output list of the recursion, "outputList", if it makes it easier for you to work with, and apply init to that:

```
keepSome y (x:xs) = init outputList
  where outputList = keepAll y (x:xs)
        keepAll _ [] = []
        keepAll y (x:xs) | x==y = y:keepAll y xs
                         | otherwise = keepAll y xs
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
*Main> keepSome 3 [1,2,3,3,3,4,5,3]
[3,3,3]    --init of the inside result, [3,3,3,3]

Answer (score 5):

First, your `keepAll` is easer written as

```
keepAll y = filter (y==)
```

Second, you can apply `length` or whatever, to the result, like in

```
length (keepAll 'a' "abrakadabra")
```

should be 5.

---

Hence, the general answer to your question "How can I apply f to the result of g" is

```
(f . g)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The implementation is not important. I am looking for a general answer, say I wanted to apply function `init` to the list after recursion.

Comment: Answered the general question.

Comment: It is the "apply my left argument to the result of application of my right argument" operator.

Comment: The . operator composes two functions together. so (f . g) x is the same as f (g x)

Comment: So I can do something like `(length . keepAll y xs)` ? to get the length of the output list from the recursion?

Comment: Almost: `(lenght . keepAll y) xs` which is just another way to write `let z = keepAll y xs in length z`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [function composition.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Function_composition)

The output of one function may be passed as input to another, like so:

```
f (g x)
```

Or

```
(f . g) x
```

Where the output type of function g is the same type as the input to f.

The (.) operator combines two such functions into a pipeline.